# Notification Sounds on every update

Tags: android, android-notifications

When i update a notification with progress, it creates a notification sound every time. This is quite annoying as it ends up being around 100 notifiction sounds. how can i stop these notification sounds on update?

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onProgress(String fileId, double progress, long downloadedBytes, long totalBytes) {
    if (!mIsList) {
        mBuilder.setProgress(100, (int) (progress * 100), false);
        mBuilder.setSound(null);
        mNotifyManager.notify(fileId.hashCode(), mBuilder.build());
    } else {
        mBuilder.setProgress(100, mCount / mFileDownloads.size(), false);
        mBuilder.setSound(null);
        mNotifyManager.notify(mFileDownloads.hashCode(), mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default way is using:

```
 mBuilder.setOnlyAlertOnce (true);
```

This will make the sound, vibrate and ticker to be played if the notification is not already showing. Just remember to pass the same id for that notification in `notify(int id,  Notification notification);`